# MVC: cannot get the syntax right for the editor template to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed view in which the first line is;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Employee.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked>>" %>
```

To avoid Id collisions I want to display the collection in a grid so I use an editor template (one of the fields gets edited).
So in my code I put in the line;

```
    <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x) %>
```

And then in the EditorTemplate sub folder I put in this template;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked>" %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: String.Format("{0:g}", Model.AnnualLeaveDate) %>
            </td>            
            <td>
                <%: Model.ApprovedStatus %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CancelFlag) %>

                <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AnnualLeaveBookedId) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The problem I am having is that the EditorFor command does not seem to recognise the EditorTemplate.
What am I doing wrong?
Incidently I would be suprised if x => x is wrong, there is probably a better way to express this.

Comment: In your case, you should simply use just the `Html.EditorForModel()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor template should be: `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/AnnualLeaveBooked.ascx` where `Home` is the name of the controller. If it is a global editor template you could also put it in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AnnualLeaveBooked.ascx`. Notice the name of the editor template: it should be the same as your type name (**`AnnualLeaveBooked.ascx`**).

Also instead of:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x) %>
```

you could:

```
<%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

Finally if you want to name your editor template with some custom name like `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Foo.ascx` you could specify this custom name:

```
<%: Html.EditorForModel("Foo") %>
```

Comment: Ok this is progress. However for <%: Html.EditorForModel("AnnualLeaveForCancellation")%> I now get the error; System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked'. This makes sense, I need to much up what I am sending and receiving between the page and the template. But what I want is the data to loop round in a grid.

Comment: @arame3333, bare in mind that `AnnualLeaveForCancellation.ascx` should be strongly typed to the `SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked` view model. That's how editor templates work.

Comment: @arame3333, your editor template should be strongly typed to `SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked` because when you are including it with `Html.EditorForModel`, your model is `AnnualLeaveBooked`. You can't just use any ascx here. Editor templates are always strongly typed to the class that's being used in the main view to include the template.

Comment: For my page declaration I have Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked>>. In my control it is <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked>" %>. Ok, so I could put IEnumerable in my control, but I think there is another way which will loop around each row to display the data in a grid

Comment: @arame3333, yes and inside your editor template you should have **`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked>"`**.

Comment: But do I then have to use a foreach loop. I thought there was a way of avoiding this?

Comment: I want to avoid foreach because I do not want duplicate Ids

Comment: No, you don't have to use any `foreach` loop. Just `<%: Html.EditorForModel() %>` and it will call the template for each element of the collection. It will also generate proper names and ids. The types need to be compatible though.

Comment: OK I think there has been confusion with the cross posting. In the page I have Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked>> and <%: Html.EditorForModel("AnnualLeaveForCancellation")%>. In the Editor Template I have <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked>" %> and the error I get is InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SHP.Models.AnnualLeaveBooked'.

Comment: @arame3333, yeap I understand now. It seems that when you specify a template name `<%: Html.EditorForModel("abc") %>` the template is not invoked for each element of the collection. That's a pity. You will need to use the default name then `AnnualLeaveBooked.ascx`.